# How to split a number string using commas in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0

How can I split a number string to date format by adding comma using c# code .
For eg:

**Input:**

```
Inputstring=20130511
```

**Output:**

```
Splitstring=2013,05,11
Year=2013
Month=05
Date=11
dayname=saturday
quater=2
```

Comment: Why not parse it directly into a `DateTime` though? also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: You have asked 5 questions and their total score is -3. Do you think you _really_ read and understand [ask] page? Or what have you tried so far to solve your problem? Remember, on the downvote button it says; **This question does not show any research effort**. Show your effort first so people show theirs.

Comment: Actually that input string is a ID field.so I can't parse directly.From that ID ,those dates should be created.

Comment: What makes you think you can't parse it? For example `var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMdd", null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a small method that takes in a string and returns a `DateTime` from your input string. You can use [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass `"yyyyMMdd"` as the [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) (which means 4-digit year, followed by 2 digit month, followed by 2 digit day). It will return the `default(DateTime)` if there's any issue with the input string:

```
private static DateTime GetDate(string input)
{
    DateTime result;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Then you could call this method and output your results like so:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var input = "20130511";
    var result = GetDate(input);

    Console.WriteLine($"Input: {input}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Year: {result.Year}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Month: {result.Month}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Date: {result.Day}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Dayname: {result.DayOfWeek}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Quarter: {(result.Month - 1) / 4 + 1}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.Sorry for adding such silly  questions,I'm not much familiar with c# code.I'm a beginner in coding

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide by a number which is multiple of 10.

For exemple : date = yyyymmdd 
If you divide date by 100 you will obtain dayTemp = yyyymm so to have your day number :

day = date - (dayTemp * 100)

Do the same to obtain month and year. you will have to change the multiple of 10.